# MODX Gallery: how to get the number of images in a folder?

Tags: gallery, modx, modx-revolution

I use MODx Revolution ver.2.20 with [Gallery module](http://modx.com/extras/package/gallery) ver.1.4.0.
So, I need to get the number of images in a folder. I googled it, but I didn't find any working solution.

How can I get it? Thanks.

Ok, this is the solution.

**Snippet** call

```
[[!GalleryAlbums? &parent=`5` &showAll=`1` &sort=`rank` &dir=`ASC` &limit=`50` &rowTpl=`b-top-img`]]
```

**b-top-img** snippet

```
      <!-- p-cover -->
      <div class="p-cover [[+id]]">
        [[!Gallery? &album=`[[+id]]` &thumbWidth=`300px` &thumbHeight=`300px` &thumbTpl=`b-middle-img`]]
      </div>
      <!-- /p-cover -->
```

**b-middle-img** chunk

```
      <div class="p"><img src="[[+thumbnail]]" alt="[[+name]]" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with PHP you can create your own snippet from this example — http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Gallery.GalleryItem.GalleryItemPagination

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I found more simple solution. I will write about this later )

Comment: I post solution. I think is simple to understand.

Comment: I see you have limit albums by 50 and then show all thumbnails for album? Where is _how to get the number of images in a folder_?